# Clear arp cache

Tags: linux, cache, arp

- How to clear arp cache ?
- How to refresh arp table ?

Comment: I assume you meant "arp cache"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arp -da
```

Then it's autorefreshing. :-)

Answer (score 6):

> How to refresh arp table ?

You can save ip from arp table:

```
arp -an | sed -s 's/.*(\([0-9.]*\)).*/\1/' > /tmp/ip_to_arp
```

And then ping all ip:

```
for ip in `cat /tmp/ip_to_arp`; do ping -c 1 ${ip}; done
```

or

```
for ip in `cat /tmp/ip_to_arp`; do arping -c 1 -I eth0 ${ip}; done
```

Comment: Can I use your script in my weblog? http://pahlevanzadeh.org , I write about freesoftware and unix, linux and programming in the freesoftware world.... of course in Persian...